# A ferris wheel completes 2 revolutions in 30 seconds. Determine how far it has travelled in 15 seconds. The radius of the ferris wheel is 10 m.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, mathematical-physics

If the Ferris wheel completes two revolutions in $30$ seconds, how many revolutions does the Ferris wheel complete in $15$ seconds? The radius of the Ferris wheel is 10 m.  I'm stuck in this question, I'm not sure how to solve it, I would appreciate it if you could help me out here, thanks!

Comment: If the ferris wheel completes two revolutions in $30$ seconds, how many revolutions does the ferris wheel complete in $15$ seconds?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that 2 revolutions in 30 seconds works out to 1 revolution every 15 seconds. The question asks the distance traveled in 15 seconds, which due to the previous calculation, works out to exactly 1 revolution.

The distance traveled in one revolution is the circumference of the wheel, which is $2 \times \pi \times 10$ m, that is $20\pi$ meter, nearly 62 m.

Comment: May I ask who downvoted this completely correct answer?

Comment: thank you @beetel , hope you have a great day :)